# Python-falcon handling session

Tags: python, session, web, falcon

I am using python flask to build a simple web app, in which user can hit a path say `localhost:8000/` and login. if login is successful, another page is displayed, but i want to know how can I redirect to the main page, if the user is already logged in ? for example, if I log in for the first time, I am taken to the main page, and if I open a second tab and again hit the url for login, I am redirected to the main page automatically( much like gmail? ).

```
class LoginPage(object):
    def on_get(self, req, resp, form={}):
```

Comment: To clarify: are you using [Falcon](https://falconframework.org/) or are you using [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/)? From the class/method it looks like Falcon, but your description mentions flask and your title falcon.

Comment: on_get is definitely a Falcon thing. If you want session management, I think Flask is a better option for you (not knowing anything else about your project). With Falcon I have tried using Beaker, which is good but its documentation is not as clear as it could be so I'm making a PR today.

Answer (score 0):

For very simple applications HTTP Basic Auth is probably good enough. Flask makes this very easy. The following decorator applied around a function that is only available for certain users does exactly that:

```
from functools import wraps
from flask import request, Response

def check_auth(username, password):
    """This function is called to check if a username password combination is valid. """
    return username == 'admin' and password == 'secret'

def authenticate():
    """Sends a 401 response that enables basic auth"""
    return Response(
    'Could not verify your access level for that URL.\n'
    'You have to login with proper credentials', 401,
    {'WWW-Authenticate': 'Basic realm="Login Required"'})

def requires_auth(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
        auth = request.authorization
        if not auth or not check_auth(auth.username, auth.password):
            return authenticate()
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return decorated
```

To use this decorator, just wrap a view function:

```
@app.route('/secret-page')
@requires_auth
def secret_page():
    return render_template('secret_page.html')
```

If you are using basic auth with mod_wsgi you will have to enable auth forwarding, otherwise apache consumes the required headers and does not send it to your application: [WSGIPassAuthorization](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationDirectives#WSGIPassAuthorization).